# Get correct rvec and tvec for camera pose estimation from SolvPnP function in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, computational-geometry, camera-calibration

I am trying to measure the pose of a camera and I have done the following.

1. Mark world 3-D(Assuming z=0, since it is flat) points on corners of a square on a flat surface and assume a world coordinate system.(in cms)

Have taken the top left corner of the square as my origin and given the world points in the following order(x,y)or(col,row):
(0,0),(-12.8,0),(-12.8,12.8),(0,12.8)   - in cms

2. Detect those points in my image.(in pixels)
   The image points and world points are in the same order.
3. I have calibrated my camera for **intrinsic matrix** and **distortion coefficients**.
4. I use **SolvePnP** function to get rvec and tvec.
5. I use **Rodrigues** function to get rotation matrix.
6. To check if rvec and tvec is correct, I project back the 3-D points(z=0) using **ProjectPoints** into the image plane and I get the points correctly on my image with an error of 3 pixels on X- axis.
7. Now I go ahead and calculate my camera position in the world frame using the formula:

**cam_worl_pos = - inverse(R) * tvec**. (This formula I have verified in many blogs and also this makes sense)

8. But my **cam_worl_pos** x,y, and z in cms do not seem to be correct.

My doubt is, if I am able to project back the 3-D world point to image plane using rvec and tvec with (**3 pixel error on X-axis and almost no error on Y axis, hope it is not too bad**), then why am I not getting the camera position in world frame right.

Also, I have a doubt on SolvPnP rvec and tvec solution, they might be one of the multiple solutions, but not the one which I want.

How do I get the right rvec and tvec from SolvPnp or any other suggestions to get rvec and tvec would also be helpful.

**EDITS** :

**Image Size** - 720(row) * 1280(col)

**Calibration pattern seen by camera**

[The link has the picture of calibration pattern used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwPml.jpg)

**New Edits**

**World coordinate system following Right Hand Rule and the corresponding points detected in the image**

[This link has the picture of the world coordinate coordinate system and also the corresponding points detected in the image plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6M9G.jpg)

The left square is my world coordinate system which is a square of sides 12.8cm, the top left corner is the world origin (0,0). The red points are the 3-D world points detected in the image.

The image seen is after radial distortion correction of a fish eye lens camera.

**camera parameters**

```
cameraMatrix_Front=[908.65   0     642.88
                     0     909.28   364.95
                     0        0        1]

distCoeffs_Front=[-0.4589, 0.09462, -1.46*10^-3, 1.23*10^-3]
```

**OpenCV C++ code**:

```
vector<Point3f> front_object_pts;
Mat rvec_front;
Mat tvec_front;
Mat rotation_front;
Mat world_position_front_cam;


//Fill front object points(x-y-z order in cms)
//It is square of side 12.8cms on Z=0 plane
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(-12.8, 0, 0));
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(-12.8,12.8,0));
front_object_pts.push_back(Point3f(0, 12.8, 0));


//Corresponding Image points detected in the same order as object points
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[0]);
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[1]);
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[2]);
front_image_pts.push_back(points_front[3]);

//Detected points in image matching the 3-D points in the same order
//(467,368)
//(512,369)
//(456,417)
//(391,416)

//Get rvec and tvec using Solve PnP
solvePnP(front_object_pts, front_image_pts, cameraMatrix_Front,
         Mat(4,1,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0)), rvec_front, tvec_front, false, CV_ITERATIVE);

//Output of SolvePnP
//tvec=[-26.951,0.6041,134.72]  (3 x 1 matrix)
//rvec=[-1.0053,0.6691,0.3752]  (3 x 1 matrix)


//Check rvec and tvec is correct or not by projecting the 3-D object points to image
vector<Point2f>check_front_image_pts
projectPoints(front_object_pts, rvec_front, tvec_front, 
             cameraMatrix_Front, distCoeffs_Front, check_front_image_pts);


//Here to note that I have made **distCoefficents**, 
//a 0 vector since my   image points are detected after radial distortion is removed

//Get rotation matrix
Rodrigues(rvec_front, rotation_front);

//Get rotation matrix inverse
Mat rotation_inverse;
transpose(rotation_front, rotation_inverse);

//Get camera position in world cordinates
world_position_front_cam = -rotation_inverse * tvec_front;
```

//Actual location of camera(Measured manualy approximate)

X=-47cm

Y=18cm

Z=25cm

//Obtained location

X=-110cm

Y=71cm

Z=40cm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I appear to be having the same issue as shown here.  Were you ever able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know `cam_worl_pos` is not correct?

`cam_worl_pos` is the position of the camera. You can try to measure the real distance between your camera and the plan where your 3D points are and compare it with the norm of `tvec` (`std::sqrt(tx²+ty²+tz²)`). It hard to say what's going wrong if you didn't share the code or the value of different parameters.

**EDIT**

If you compute the distance from `tvec` it gives you `137.390683 cm`: `std::sqrt(26.951*26.951+0.6041*0.6041+134.72*134.72)`

You can check if that is correct by measuring the real distance!

And also how do you measure the location of your camera with respect to the world frame manually?

**EDIT2**

If you don't get the right values then something is wrong in the parameters of solvePnP function:

- Your `cameraMatrix_Front` seems to be correct. But make sure that `908.65 * CCD (mm)=focal length (mm)`
- Pass the real values of distortion coefficient you get from calibration to solvePnP
- You need at least four points to `solvePnP` (the more points the better) and for more accuracy don't make your plan (where your square is) parallel to the image plan like:

[image]

But something more like that, in perspective in any direction:
[image]

**EDIT3**

- Try with more images with different square position and why not in live and moving the camera
- Make sure you did everything I asked you before in 
  **EDIT2**: `cameraMatrix_Front`, distortion coefficient..etc

Comment: Hi, I have added the camera parameters and also the OpenCV C++ code, please check and let me know .

Comment: @Nithin I just edited my answer!! it's not easy to measure the location of the camera manually because you've x, y and z!!

Comment: I used a measuring tape from the origin of the world..i.e the left top corner of the square. It should be atleast close to these values right...not that 'off', what I am getting...

Comment: That what I'm asking you to do! what you measure in real world is what you get with std::sqrt(tx²+ty²+tz²) so it is a single value = the distance!

Comment: ok...The actaul "distance" is around 70cm and I am getting around 135cm using the formula...so SolvePnP is going wrong...but why?

Comment: But when I use rvec and tvec to project 3-D points to image plane, I get the right points back with 3 pixel error on X axis....how is this happening??This means tvec and rvec is correct right .. but on the other hand when I tried ur experiment of calculating the distance, then it is not correct.. I am confused

Comment: I have added the calibration pattern used, please check. Now you may have a better idea.